# Installing an external USB SSD drive on my windows10 PRO laptop is not working

Tags: windows-10, usb, ssd

Hello experts:  I have a windows 10Pro O/S on an HP business laptop.  I have 2 external AC powered usb hard drives installed and for the most part they work fine (at times the O/S will not see them but lately everything is good).  I also have a USB BluRay R/W drive installed and it's working fine.
I recently bought 2 new USB SSD 128TB external drives.  One seems to be defective as the O/S won't recognize it at all.  The 2nd one is recognized BUT it will not initialize/format/etc.  Can't do anything with it.  I'm scratching my head as this laptop/OS seems to work fine on the other USB devices but not these new drives.
Questions:

- Is there a limit on USB Devices on a windows 10 O/S?
- The other USB devices have been plug/play but not these new guys.  Normal?
- Any ideas are appreciated.
  Thanks,
  Ille

Comment: There is a **power** limit on USB ports, with different versions of the USB standard having differing limits. You mention the existing USB external drives have separate power supplies; do the new 12 TB drives? Quick test: unplug all other USB devices (except perhaps keyboard and mouse) and try the drives again.

Comment: 128tb? Did you mean 128gb?  That would seem either stupid expensive (for 128tb) or concerningly old stock - are you sure the drives are not faulty.  Relatedly, are you sure theu are SSD and not just SD?